# Problema con un arreglo de struct

Tags: c++

Tengo una variable en un struct que se llama nombreTema, es un char. A la hora del código, pregunta cuantas materias quieres agregar, incluyo 2 materias, luego pregunta el numero de temas de esa materia, digamos mate1,mate2, y así, vuelve a pedir hasta que termina las materias solicitadas y el numero de temas solicitados a escoger, pero a la hora de imprimir, todo se imprime muy bien, pero los temas nunca los toma en cuenta, meto mate1, mate2, nomas me guarda mate 2, supongo que es porque se guarda en la variable char nombre tema del struct, pero no se como hacer que se guarden mas y los muestre, alguna sugerencia?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

struct carrera{
    char ncarrera[50];
};

struct temas{
    char nombreTema[20];
    int numtemas=0;


};

struct materias {
    char nmaterias[20];
    struct temas info_temas;
    struct carrera info_carrera;
};


int main() {
    int y=0;
    int aux=0;
    cout<<"Cuantas materias quieres registrar?"<<endl;
    cin>>y;
    fflush(stdin);
    materias materia[y];


    for(int i=0; i<y; i++) {
    
        cout << "Nombre de Materia: ";
        cin.getline(materia[i].nmaterias,20);
        cout<<"Cantidad de temas";
        cin>>materia[i].info_temas.numtemas;
        fflush(stdin);
        aux=materia[i].info_temas.numtemas;


        for(int x=0; x<aux; x++){
            cout<<"Nombre del tema";
            cin.getline(materia[i].info_temas.nombreTema,20);
        }

    }

    for(int a=0; a<y; a++){
        cout<<"Materia: "<<materia[a].nmaterias<<endl<<"temas: "<<materia[a].info_temas.nombreTema<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto no se puede hacer:

```
cin>>y;
fflush(stdin);
materias materia[y];
```

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), las formaciones deben tener un tamaño que se conozca en tiempo de compilación, una variable por definición no lo es. Si quieres una colección de datos cuyo tamaño pueda ser definido en tiempo de ejecución usa `std::vector`:

```
cin>>y;
fflush(stdin);
std::vector<materias> materia(y);
```